# Trying to get a javascript widget to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning how to build widgets, so I started off with a simple widget that when clicked on alerted Hey on whatever website you placed the widget on, which is a function defined in the source website. So here is the code on the source website

```
(function(){
var jQuery;

if (window.jQuery==undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery!=='1.8.1'){
var script_tag=document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js");

if(script_tag.readyState){
script_tag.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState=='complete' || this.readyState=='loaded'){
    scriptLoadHandler();
    }
    };
}else{
    script_tag.onload=scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}else{
jQuery=window.jQuery;
main();
}

function scriptLoadHandler(){
jQuery=window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
main();
}

function main(){
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.widget').click(function(){
    alert("Hey");
    });
});
}
})();
```

Now here is the code of the widget to be placed on any website

```
<script src="http://www.reflap.com/beta/assets/js/widget2.js"></script>
<a class="widget" href="#">Hey</a>
```

But when I click on Hey nothing happens. What's wrong? Can someone help me out here.

Comment: change `$('.widget').click(function(){ alert("Hey"); });` to this `$('.widget').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert("Hey"); });` you have the stop the browser from following the link

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

to your code,i tried that on this [JFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47KKu/)

i hope this is what you look for.